# what is the difference between Test pin and Ready pin in 8086 microprocessor?

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

can you tell me difference between Test pin and Ready pin in 8086 microprocessor because both of them deal with wait instructions?

TEST: input is examined by the ‘‘Wait’’ instruction. If the TEST input is
LOW execution continues, otherwise the processor waits in an ‘‘Idle’’
state. This input is synchronized internally during each clock cycle on
the leading edge of CLK.

READY: is the acknowledgement from the addressed memory or I/O
device that it will complete the data transfer. The READY signal from
memory/IO is synchronized by the 8284A Clock Generator to form
READY. This signal is active HIGH. The 8086 READY input is not
synchronized. Correct operation is not guaranteed if the setup and hold
times are not met.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the description of the READY signal, the wait instruction is not mentioned.

The READY signal is sampled on each and every memory or I/O cycle. If a device is not capable of responding to the CPU's request in the standard bus cycle, the READY signal can be used to stretch out the cycle, giving it more time.

This is done by signalling to the CPU that the device is not READY. The CPU adds a clock cycles to the bus transaction until it is READY. These extra cycles are given the confusing name of "WAIT STATES", and have nothing to do with the WAIT instruction or the TEST line. Many years ago, makers of fast memory would brag "No wait states!"

The part about the 8284a refers to the details of ensuring that the READY input meets the timing requirements of the processor. Namely the so called setup and hold times, normally only of concern to the engineer designing the computer system.

In your question, you can see that the TEST input is explicitly sampled by the WAIT instruction. The TEST input is simply an input signal with a dedicated pin on the processor (TEST) sampled by a dedicated instruction (WAIT).

Most processors have signals similar to the READY line. The TEST line is rather more rare.